# How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way?

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces, gnome-shell

Gnome-shell seems to like to leave one monitor as "fixed" when you switch workspaces.

Additionally, there is no preview in the Activities view of my secondary monitor.

Also, on the second monitor, where there should be either empty desktop space, or a copy of the panel, I just have a white bar.

How can I get gnome-shell to treat my secondary monitor like the primary one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting `workspaces-only-on-primary false` (using `gsetting`, `gconftool`, GNOME Tweak or whatever – see all other answers) **only solves the first problem:**

> Gnome-shell seems to like to leave one monitor as "fixed" when you switch workspaces.

For the second problem

> Additionally, there is no preview in the Activities view of my secondary monitor.

there is a [GNOME extension called Multi Monitors Add-On](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) that Just Works™. (See also [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions))

Comment: This solution provides the final piece of the puzzle.  The other answers all address having workspace behaviour on secondary monitors, but not having the preview of both in activities view.  Thanks for solving my 7 year old problem. :)

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 18):

## 14.04

In later versions of Gnome, you have to open `gnome-tweak-tool` and, under "Workspaces", change the "Workspaces only on primary display" setting.

Comment: I use 14.04 with gnome-shell from standard repositories and this does not work for me. The switch does not change anything.

Comment: Don't have enought reputation to comment fossfreedom answer and Ted Barth comment, so I add a new answer: on 14.04, this trick works, but you need to reboot to apply changes.

Comment: there is no "Workspaces only on primary display" menu item in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: this need to be done again after you upgrade to 16.04 ;)

Comment: This works for me in Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: This only solves the first problem, but not the second one. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/16985

Answer (score 14):

I could not find the /desktop/gnome/shell/windows key mentioned by Martin, but the source he's quoting says to run:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

This fixed it instantly for me. Thanks, gregcor (the source).

Comment: Alas, this didn't work for me in Ubuntu 14.04. (see my follow up question http://askubuntu.com/questions/558717/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way-ubuntu-14-04-tru )

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 it doesn't work

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS this answer does seem to work for me. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1086531/340383

Comment: This only solves the first problem, but not the second one. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/16985

Comment: Ubuntu 18. Works great.

Answer (score 13):

Regarding the fixed second monitor, there's an easy way to fix that as I have just found out. If I may quote:

> 1. Download gconf-editor – this is probably available in your distribution’s package manager.
> 2. Start gconf-editor – the “Run Command” menu is still available in GNOME 3 by pressing Alt-F2.
> 3. In the tree on the left, navigate to /desktop/gnome/shell/windows
> 4. UNCHECK the box next to workspaces_only_on_primary

Source: http://gregcor.com/2011/05/07/fix-dual-monitors-in-gnome-3-aka-my-workspaces-are-broken/

Comment: Thanks for that!  That solves the problem in terms of switching workspace with the keyboard, but in the activities view the second monitor shows windows from the second monitor of all workspaces.  Hopefully they work on multi monitor support in the future.

Comment: See other answers ... this solution is depreciated.

Comment: Confirmed this is deprecated in 18.04.1 LTS. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1086531/340383

Comment: @Alex for the Activities problem, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/16985

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by installing *GNOME Tweaks* from Ubuntu Software. After installation, it shows in apps drawer as *Tweaks*. The package name is actually called `gnome-tweak-tool`.

[image]

The option you are looking for is located in the **Workspaces** tab, and it is called *Workspaces span displays*.

Comment: I can't find `Tweaks`. Is there a certain repository I need to have?

Comment: No special repository, it is in `universe`. Application name is `GNOME Tweaks` in Ubuntu Software. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: use `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`. You as well should be able to find it with this name in the Software-Center.

Comment: It's already in the answer

Comment: This only solves the first problem, but not the second one. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/16985

Answer (score 1):

My ubuntu 18.04 with unity has the same problem.
Using the `gconf-editor` [suggested by Martin](https://askubuntu.com/a/75570/384849), the box I need to uncheck located at `/org/gnome/mutter/workspaces-only-on-primary`.

Answer (score 1):

## 18.04.1 LTS

https://askubuntu.com/a/393355/340383 is *the* correct answer. Posting this to warn others of what seems to me to be a bug:

Adding a checkbox beside *Workspaces span displays* inside the tweak tool has no effect:

[image: broken workspaces tweaks window]

I also could not find a `/desktop/gnome/shell` key shown by `gconf-editor` as indicated by the https://askubuntu.com/a/393355/340383 answer.

**Update 2019-03-22 07:03**: Please also read the commentary for this answer, as the "does NOT have any effect at all" in the picture above may be invalid with subsequent releases *after* **18.04.1 LTS**, and that I've not retried the setting since I posted this answer.

Comment: what do you mean by _no effect_? it solves one of the two problems by OP, at least on 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: "it solves" is ambiguous. Please specify which of the answers you are referring to that solves the problem. And I do not see that the OP has marked any of the answers as the correct answer yet.

Comment: I was referring to the action (changing the _Display Handling_ setting to _Workspaces span displays_, mentioned by multiple answers above) that you claim to _“NOT have any effect”_ at all. Contrary to your claim stated in red, it indeed solves the first half of the problem in the question (_leave one monitor as "fixed"_). for the second half (_there is no preview in the Activities view_), see https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/16985

Comment: Your criticism is logged against my saying "does NOT have any effect at all" since I didn't clarify what I observed there in text or in pictures. Duly noted.  Unfortunately, my system has likely undergone an upgrade from "18.04.1 LTS" by this point in Mar 22 2019, so I would be hard pressed to correct my notes. Do note that my primary goal with this answer was to warn people about what I consider a bug in GNOME, and to indicate what worked for me in "18.04.1 LTS" (that may actually have been recified in subsequent releases).

Comment: I added *Update 2019-03-22 07:03* to warn others about the information being "stale".

Comment: Oh, I have not noticed the version difference. That makes sense. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

found another nice solution where both monitors have separate workspaces:

```
git clone git://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on.git
cd multi-monitors-add-on
git branch -a && git checkout gnome-3-32_3-36
cp -r multi-monitors-add-on@spin83 ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

`alt` + `F2` type in `r` then `enter`

then, you can open your tweaks application on Ubuntu, described above and find there `extensions` and activate `multi-monitors add-on` if it's not already activated.

Note: I struggled with error where extension could not have been properly loaded due to errors, you can debug them by reading journal log output:

```
sudo journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell
```

if that's the case try switching the branch in repository above

or report the error to the owner on GitHub

https://github.com/spin83/multi-monitors-add-on.git

**Good luck everybody :)**