# Dual Monitors: Cannot switch workspace on VGA monitor

Tags: gnome, 13.10, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have a dual monitor setup with an internal laptop monitor and an external VGA monitor (extended, not mirrored). When I now switch workspaces, this only happens on the internal monitor; windows on the external monitor are always "sticky"!

What I would want is the workspace stretching over both the internal monitor as well as the extended external monitor, and **switching workspaces should have the same effect on both monitors**.

I do **not** want to establish separated workspaces on each monitor which are switchable individually. This is a feature for which I found several questions here on the platform, but for my specific problem I was not able to find a solution or even a matching question...

My system is an Ubuntu 13.10 (currently with Gnome Shell) with kernel 3.12. The laptop has an nVidia Optimus graphics adapter; I basically always rely on the precessor's internal graphics adapter.

Thanks in advance!

/edit:

I resolved the issue now. It turned out that it is actually a Gnome problem, this is why I did not find anything with my Ubuntu related search attempts.

You find the solution here: http://gregcor.com/2011/05/07/fix-dual-monitors-in-gnome-3-aka-my-workspaces-are-broken/

The desired behavior is activated by executing

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

in a shell.

/edit (2017-10-26):

The sketched solution does not work anymore for me in Ubuntu 17.10. A working solution is given in this answer: [How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way#answer-558723):

> open gnome-tweak-tool and, under "Workspaces", change the "Workspaces only on primary display" setting.

Comment: You should have answered your own question instead of editing it - this is totally what I was looking for!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way)

Answer (score 0):

--copied the answer from an edit the OP made to their question --

You find the solution here: http://gregcor.com/2011/05/07/fix-dual-monitors-in-gnome-3-aka-my-workspaces-are-broken/

The desired behavior is activated by executing

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary false`

in a shell.