# How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way (Ubuntu 14.04 trusty edition)?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have basically the same problem as was asked in [this question from 2011](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way), namely Gnome-shell leaves one monitor fixed when I switch workspaces. I would like to be able to have both monitors switch workspaces at the same time, so that I have more total screen space to work with.

Neither of the two solutions ([a](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way/393355#393355) and [b](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way/75570#75570)) solve the problem for me. Since both of those solutions are from 2011, 3 years ago, I wonder if something has changed, and if there is some new solution to this problem (or alternatively, has someone had those solutions work for them, which means there's something wrong with my set up).