# Workspace options in gnome-tweak-tool are inactive

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I am trying to change some of the workspace options in Ubuntu 17.10. I do not particularly like many of the changes to the default settings. In particular, I do not like how workspaces are only "vertical" now and not in an X by X grid anymore. Also, I want to change the behavior that seems to prevent one of my two monitors from "participating" in the workspace.

I have seen a few people explain that this can be fixed with the gnome-tweak-tool such as here: [How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way)

However, when I try to change the settings under the "workspaces" tab, all the options are gray and cannot be clicked on.

Is there a way to make the workspaces tab active, so I can change these settings?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the issue.

This is a UI glitch.

The widget is not a checkbox, but a radio. You need to click on the other option "Workspaces scan displays".

That's that simple ...

Comment: "Workspaces scan displays" ->  "Workspaces span displays". I suppose

Comment: I am not sure it is that simple. @DanielSaunders problem (and mine too) with "X by X grid" seems not to be fixed with switching to "Workspaces span displays". The workspaces are still vertical.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Settings > Multitasking section