# Dual monitor workspaces in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, workspaces, activities-overview

Dual monitor setup on Ubuntu 18.04; when I hit activities only the left monitor switches workspaces while the right monitor just keeps whatever is on its screen. Is there a way to make the workspace span both monitors so that when I switch from one workspace to another both monitors switch?

Comment: Does this work for both gnome and unity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way)

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Had the same problem. Turned out it was super easy to fix.

Install the GNOME Tweaks app. Go to **Workspaces** and set **Display handling** to **Workspaces span displays**. Done!

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/16985 for additional fixes, e.g. Activities still showing windows from all workspaces on secondary display

Comment: I had a different problem that this solution fixed. When switching from a single laptop display to a single external display, all the windows were merged into the top workspace, emptying the other workspace. Makes the worksspaces concept useless. Thanks.

Comment: This fixes workspaces but the "window key" dash on additional monitors shows all apps across all workspaces for Ubuntu 18. In Fedora 31, this works.

Comment: Did this but it had no effect. Changing workspace has effect on primary monitor only

Comment: I searched for the reverse to keep a zoom session on 2nd monitor while switching workspaces in sharing my screen.  Indeed gnome-tweaks: switch "workspaces span displays" to "workspaces on primary display only".  Thanks!

Comment: PSA: "Workspaces" is not available anymore in the Tweaks app in Ubuntu 22.04, but the solution below using gsettings still works.

Comment: Does the workspace overview/thumbnail show what's on the secondary display? On my end it does not. Any suggestiongs?

Answer (score 133):

You can change this behaviour by executing:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This worked on my Budgie desktop as well.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on 19.10

Comment: Just upgraded to 18.04, and use Unity. Solved the problem for me, thanks.

Comment: This work on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: God bless you!!!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20

Comment: honorary accepted answer. worked on Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: @dkurzaj it did something on ubuntu 20.04 but doesn't allow for independent workspaces on each monitor. They all change at the same time. Slightly disappointing

Comment: @ionescho the question is about  "mak[ing] the workspace span both monitors", not having different workspaces on the different monitors. I'm sorry, but I do not know how to do what you want :/ Maybe have a look at this other topic : https://askubuntu.com/questions/21711/multiple-monitors-multiple-workspaces

Comment: Amazing. It works also on 20.04. Curiosity: where are such settings stored?

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 20):

You can install `gnome-tweak-tool` via `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`.

Then go to **Workspaces > Display Handling >** And choose *Workspaces span displays*

Answer (score 18):

In **Ubuntu 22.04**:

```
Settings > Multitasking > Multi-Monitor > Workspaces on all displays
```

Answer (score 13):

Install `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Disable the following settings:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/workspaces-only-on-primary false
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/overrides/workspaces-only-on-primary false
```

Comment: @leoschet I suggest you reset dconf settings first. (dconf reset -f /)

Comment: I don't think you need to install `dconf-editor` (it's for the **GUI application**) first in order to run the `dconf write ...` commands. Also it's preferable to use `gsettings` instead of the `dconf` commands (see [here](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html)).

Answer (score 10):

I recommend to you to use the [Multi Monitos Add-on](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) extension, available in [GNOME Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org). It is pretty easy to use, and it also gives you the ability to add a panel in the second monitor.

To get up and running all the GNOME extensions config directly in your browser, you only need the following:

1. Install the gnome-shell-extensions package:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
   ```
2. Install the host connector:

   ```
   sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
   ```
3. Install the GNOME Shell integration [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gnome-shell-integration/gphhapmejobijbbhgpjhcjognlahblep) (Chrome) or [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gnome-shell-integration/?src=search) (Firefox).
4. Find and install the [Multi Monitos Add-on](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) extension.

Comment: I'm slightly disappointed to find that this still doesnt allow for independent desktop state on each monitor.

Comment: @StevenLu I changed to MacOS only for that feature ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: at least multi desktop is usable in ubuntu but it's clearly lacking a few touches