# dual monitor workspaces on triple monitor setup in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I used [dual monitor workspaces in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059479/dual-monitor-workspaces-in-ubuntu-18-04) to get dual monitor workspaces to switch properly on my dual screen. However, I'd like the laptop screen to not have workspaces, and just be available for messaging etc. How can I have workspaces span my two main screens, but the other display ignore workspace switching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the exact solution, but may be suit you.

You can set "Always on visible workspace"(in window menu) for applications you want to see on any workspace. Set it for apps you want always visible on laptop display.

Its possible propably to use xprop to set this option in shell script, but I don't known how exactly. Will update answer when find how to do it.

Comment: This is good enough for me. :)