# Ubuntu 18.04: How do I move a terminal to a different workspace?

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I upgraded my system for 14.04. to 18.04. To switch between workspaces I use Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down. This works fine for all applications except the terminal which follows to the new workspace. Is there a way to change this behavior of the terminal or move it to another workspace?

Comment: Are you using Unity or Gnome which is set by default in 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd> to move the window in focus between workspaces.

Similarly, use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> to move to first or last workspace as required.

The left <kbd>Windows</kbd> key is usually set as as the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did not realize that the problem is not liked to the terminal, but on which of my two screens, the terminal/programma is running. A possible solution may be:

[Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059479/dual-monitor-workspaces-in-ubuntu-18-04)