# De-couple workspaces in case of dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces

I'm looking for the following:

- Dual monitor setup with both monitors (say named  M1 and M2) supporting workspaces
- The workspaces in Monitor1 (M1) are indepdent of Monitor2 (M2)

  - If I switch workspace on M1, the one on M2 shouldn't change
  - If I switch workspace on M2, the one on M1 shouldn't change

I am already aware of solutoins like these, where the workspace spans both the monitors ([dual monitor workspaces in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059479/dual-monitor-workspaces-in-ubuntu-18-04)). And this is not what I'm looking for.

Whereas what I'm looking for is how it behaves on operating systems like MacOS.

Comment: The best and easiest way is indeed through gnome tweaks as suggested in that link.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha: I clearly mentioned in my comment that I need de-coupled workspaces.. So that doesn't work for me

Comment: Sorry. My bad...