# Problem with multiple monitors and workspaces

Tags: 18.04

Maybe you have an idea how to fix a problem I have.

I have 2 monitors.

When hitting windows/super key I see all open windows on current workspace.

This works well for the right hand monitor.

However, on the left hand monitor I see all open windows independent of the workspace.

Do you have any idea what this might be?

I would like to have an isolated workspace, when hitting the win key to show only the open applications in this current workspace.

I tested already the following command:

```bsh
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-workspaces true
```

It didn't work.

To be clear, I'm talking about the Activities overview which shows all open windows in current workspace.

Windows on right monitor are only shown in the overview when I'm on this workspace. However, on left monitor all windows are shown every time.

Here is an example of my screens
[image]
Hitting `super` key
[image]

As you can see, on current worksapce I only have gedit open on right screen. However if I hit `super` key, it also shows firefox which is open on a different workspace on left screen. But I only want to see open applications on current workspace, which is just gedit in this case.

Solution: Follow instruction found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/169671

Comment: I feel like a few screenshots could really help out here.

Comment: Updated my question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you meant on `I see all open windows independent of the workspace`. Do you mean you see all windows in the system, or all windows in the left screen only?
So, in the end, do you mean you want to hit Super key, and only open overview on one screen only, or to show on both screen as usual, but only show what's on that independent screen only?

If it's the first case, I don't think that can be done easily.
But if you just want separate overview for each screen, it's quite simple.
If you have GNOME Tweaks installed, open it, go to `Workspaces`. Under `Display Handling`, select `Workspaces on primary display only`.
Otherwise, you can just run
`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary true`
`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary true`

If you need the reversed, set to the other option in GNOME Tweaks, or run
`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter workspaces-only-on-primary false`
`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.overrides workspaces-only-on-primary false`
After that, check out this answer at
https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/1476180
to make overview work properly

Comment: If I hit Super Key I see all open applications on current workspace. However, if the window is on my left monitor (not primary display) I see all windows open on all workspaces. For windows on primary display it works as expected. I usually open many windows on multiple workspaces. The whole point of workspace is to have isolated space to work on. But for windows on my left screen I see all open applications. `Workspaces on primary display only` is exactly what I don't want. I want a workspace both combined.

Comment: Edited answer, is this what you need?

Comment: Please see my original question.

Comment: Did you even try my edited part? If you didn't, you should.

Comment: Sorry, missed the point which referred to https://askubuntu.com/a/1125322/1476180 ... this worked perfectly. Thanks.